# Swiper arrows not visible and pagination is shot off of the bottom of the page (not the bottom of the slides)

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I enabled swiper for the page that I am building and I have the following settings for it:

```
  const swiper3 = new Swiper('.ingredients-swiper', {
    grabCursor: true,
    direction: 'horizontal', 

    pagination: {
      el: '.swiper-pagination',
    },

    navigation: {
      nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
      prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
    },

    scrollbar: {
      el: '.swiper-scrollbar',
    },
  });
```

These are basically the default settings that I have copy/pasted from the get started page of Swiper.

The problem is that the pagination controls and arrows are nowhere to be found.

Arrows have `display: none` and pagination is set to the bottom, but the bottom of the screen, and not the bottom of the slides.

A live preview can be seen here:

https://www.bangcookies.com/pages/ingredients?preview_theme_id=120521556066

I have followed the structure as described in the documentation:

```
<div class="ingredients-swiper">
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <div class="swiper-slide"></div>
    ...restofslides...
  </div>
  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>

  <!-- If we need navigation buttons -->
  <div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
  <div class="swiper-button-next"></div>

  <!-- If we need scrollbar -->
  <div class="swiper-scrollbar"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: When I inspected the element on the demo page, it looks like display none is being set by this class

a:empty, article:empty, div:empty, dl:empty, h1:empty, h2:empty, h3:empty, h4:empty, h5:empty, h6:empty, p:empty, section:empty, ul:empty {
    /* display: none; */
}

When i disabled it, the buttons showed up. I don't know anything about shopify really, but the css is for hiding them.

Answer (score -1):

I took a brief look at your example. Site looks very nice. When i adjusted your arrows from `display:none` to `display:inline block` your arrows will now appear.

Then your absolute positioning needs to be adjusted.
In `.swiper-button-next, .swiper-button-prev { }`

Remove the `top:50%`  and your arrows will display at the bottom or adjust as you need